# Wordpress Custom Post Type Image Uploader Issue

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, image-uploading, custom-post-type

I have a bug with my Custom Post Type Image Uploader i can't get my head around.
My image uploader is working perfectly fine, when i upload my images all at once, but if i need to edit a post then my issue comes. When i press the update button in Wordpress admin, all my images are deleted and only a broken image is left. 
The Images is only saved if i have used the media uploader, before pressing update. So if i want to edit a post i have to uploade the images every time, and i need to fix that.

I have two files: image_uploader.php and image_upload.js.

First one image_upload.js and second image_uploader.php

```js
var addButton = document.getElementById( 'image-upload-button');
var deleteButton = document.getElementById( 'image-delete-button');
var img = document.getElementById( 'image-tag');
var hidden = document.getElementById( 'img-hidden-field');
var customUploader = wp.media({
 title: 'Choose an image',
 button: {
  text: "Use this Image"
 },
 multiple: false

});

addButton.addEventListener( 'click', function() {
  if ( customUploader ){
   customUploader.open();
  }
 
} );
customUploader.on( 'select', function() {
    var attachment = customUploader.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
    img.setAttribute( 'src', attachment.url );
    hidden.setAttribute( 'value', JSON.stringify( [{ id: attachment.id, url: attachment.url }]) );
 toggleVisibility( 'ADD' );
} );

deleteButton.addEventListener( 'click', function(){
 img.removeAttribute( 'src' );
 hidden.removeAttribute( 'value' );
 toggleVisibility( 'DELETE' );
});

var toggleVisibility = function( action ) {
    if ( 'ADD' === action ) {
        addButton.style.display = 'none';
        deleteButton.style.display = '';
        img.setAttribute( 'style', 'width: 100%;' );
    }

    if ( 'DELETE' === action ) {
        addButton.style.display = '';
        deleteButton.style.display = 'none';
        img.removeAttribute('style');
    }
};


window.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    if ( "" === customUploads.imageData || 0 === customUploads.imageData.length ) {
        toggleVisibility( 'DELETE' );
    } else {
        img.setAttribute( 'src', customUploads.imageData.src );
        hidden.setAttribute( 'value', JSON.stringify([ customUploads.imageData ]) );
        toggleVisibility( 'ADD' );
    }
} );

// Second Image
var addButton2 = document.getElementById( 'image-upload-button2');
var deleteButton2 = document.getElementById( 'image-delete-button2');
var img2 = document.getElementById( 'image-tag2');
var hidden2 = document.getElementById( 'img-hidden-field2');
var customUploader2 = wp.media({
 title: 'Choose an image',
 button: {
  text: "Use this Image"
 },
 multiple: false

});

addButton2.addEventListener( 'click', function() {
  if ( customUploader2 ){
   customUploader2.open();
  }
 
} );

customUploader2.on( 'select', function() {
    var attachment2 = customUploader2.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
    img2.setAttribute( 'src', attachment2.url );
    hidden2.setAttribute( 'value', JSON.stringify( [{ id: attachment2.id, url: attachment2.url }]) );
 toggleVisibility2( 'ADD2' );
} );

deleteButton2.addEventListener( 'click', function(){
 img2.removeAttribute( 'src' );
 hidden2.removeAttribute( 'value' );
 toggleVisibility2( 'DELETE2' );
});

var toggleVisibility2 = function( action ) {
    if ( 'ADD2' === action ) {
        addButton2.style.display = 'none';
        deleteButton2.style.display = '';
        img2.setAttribute( 'style', 'width: 100%;' );
    }

    if ( 'DELETE2' === action ) {
        addButton2.style.display = '';
        deleteButton2.style.display = 'none';
        img2.removeAttribute('style');
    }
};


window.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    if ( "" === customUploads2.imageData2 || 0 === customUploads2.imageData2.length ) {
        toggleVisibility2( 'DELETE2' );
    } else {
        img2.setAttribute( 'src', customUploads2.imageData2.src );
        hidden2.setAttribute( 'value', JSON.stringify([ customUploads2.imageData2 ]) );
        toggleVisibility2( 'ADD2' );
    }
} );
```

```html
<?php
 // Meta box 1
  function register_metaboxes() {
   add_meta_box('image_metabox', 'Billeder','image_uploader_callback');
  }
  add_action( 'add_meta_boxes','register_metaboxes' );
  
  // Meta box 2
 function register_metaboxes2() {
   add_meta_box('image2_metabox', 'Billeder2','image2_uploader_callback');
  }
  add_action( 'add_meta_boxes','register_metaboxes2' );

function register_admin_script() {
   wp_enqueue_script( 'wp_img_upload', 'image-upload.js', array('jquery', 'media-upload'), true );
   
  wp_localize_script( 'wp_img_upload', 'customUploads', array( 'imageData' => get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'custom_image_data', true ) ) );
  wp_localize_script( 'wp_img_upload', 'customUploads2', array( 'imageData2' => get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'custom_image2_data', true ) ) );

add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'register_admin_script' );

function image_uploader_callback( $post_id ) {
   wp_nonce_field( basename( __FILE__ ), 'custom_image_nonce' ); ?>

   <div id="metabox_wrapper">
    <img id="image-tag">
    <input type="hidden" id="img-hidden-field" name="custom_image_data">
    <input type="button" id="image-upload-button" class="button" value="Add Image">
    <input type="button" id="image-delete-button" class="button" value="Delete Image">
   </div>
   <?php
  }
  function image2_uploader_callback( $post_id ) { 

     wp_nonce_field( basename( __FILE__ ), 'custom_image2_nonce' ); ?>
    
    <label>Andet billede</label>
    <div id="metabox_wrapper2">
     <img id="image-tag2">
     <input type="hidden" id="img-hidden-field2" name="custom_image2_data">
     <input type="button" id="image-upload-button2" class="button" value="Add Image">
     <input type="button" id="image-delete-button2" class="button" value="Delete Image">
    </div>
   <?php
  }

function save_custom_image( $post_id ) {
   $is_autosave = wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id );
   $is_revision = wp_is_post_revision( $post_id );
   $is_valid_nonce = ( isset( $_POST[ 'custom_image_nonce' ] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST[ 'custom_image_nonce' ], basename( __FILE__ ) ) );
   $image_data = ['id','src'];
   
   // Exits script depending on save status
   if ( $is_autosave || $is_revision || !$is_valid_nonce ) {
    return;
   }
   if ( isset( $_POST[ 'custom_image_data' ] ) ) {
    $image_data = json_decode( stripslashes( $_POST[ 'custom_image_data' ] ) );
    if ( is_object( $image_data[0] ) ) {
     $image_data = array( 'id' => intval( $image_data[0]->id ), 'src' => esc_url_raw( $image_data[0]->url
     ) );
    } 
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'custom_image_data', $image_data );
   }
  }

  add_action( 'save_post', 'save_custom_image' );
  
  // Image 2
  function save_custom_image2( $post_id ){
   $is_autosave2 = wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id );
   $is_revision2 = wp_is_post_revision( $post_id );
   $is_valid_nonce2 = ( isset( $_POST[ 'custom_image2_nonce' ] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST[ 'custom_image2_nonce' ], basename( __FILE__ ) ) );
   
   // Exits script depending on save status
   if ( $is_autosave2 || $is_revision2 || !$is_valid_nonce2 ) {
    return;
   }
   if ( isset( $_POST[ 'custom_image2_data' ] ) ) {
    $image_data2 = json_decode( stripslashes( $_POST[ 'custom_image2_data' ] ) );
    if ( is_object( $image_data2[0] ) ) {
     $image_data2 = array( 'id' => intval( $image_data2[0]->id ), 'src' => esc_url_raw( $image_data2[0]->url
     ) );
    } else {
     $image_data2 = [];
    }
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'custom_image2_data', $image_data2 );
    }
   } 
  add_action( 'save_post', 'save_custom_image2' );
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what do you try to accomplish there and it's quite hard to debug your code without setting up new installation, but I think there is better way to do that.

Wordpress have very useful extension called ACF https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/ which gives you possibility to add custom meta fields to one or multiple post types. I highly recommend it, even free version is enough for most of the cases.

Comment: I see, thanks. I am familier with the plugins out there, but because this is a school project, i cant use the plugins.

Comment: oh, that's weird. Free version is open source, just to let you know, so as long as your school doesn't state that you cannot use any other software it should be fine. I am afraid I cannot help you as probably my employer wouldn't be happy about an hour debugging of website of someone from stackoverflow :) sorry and good luck.

Comment: Good school by the way and good that you are doing more advanced things then most of the wp developers even don't know how to do.